# How to find a solaris process with ___ status

Tags: perl, unix, shell, process, solaris

I made the following script which searches for certain processes, displays uses pflags for each one, and stops when it finds one with the word "pause":

```
!cat find_pause
#!/usr/bin/perl -W

use warnings;
use strict;

if (open(WCF,
         "ps -ef | grep '/transfile' | cut -c10-15 | xargs -n1 pflags 2>&1 |"
   )) {
    while (<WCF>) {
       next if ($_ =~ /cannot/);
       print $_;
       last if ($_ =~ /pause/);
    }
    close(WCF);
}
```

It works, but I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

### Update

`pause` is a low-level system call.  Like `read`, `nanosleep`, `waitid`, etc.

With this script I want to find processes that are stuck in the `pause` call.  We are trying to find a bug in our system, and we think it might be related to this.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly "pause" means in `pflags` output? It's nowhere in `proc` pr `pflags` manpages and all the actual flags are upper case.

Comment: it sounds like "pause" would be in the "status"? If so I updated the first example with plausible logic

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible improvements to this, depending on:

1. Do you actually require to print exact output of `pflags` command or some info from it (e.g. list of PIDs and flags?)
2. What does "pause" in pflags output mean? It's nowhere in "proc" or "pflags" man-pages and all the actual flags are upper case. Depending on its meaning, it might be found in native Perl implementation of "/proc" - [Proc::processTable::Process](http://search.cpan.org/~durist/Proc-ProcessTable-0.45/Process/Process.pm).

   For example, that Process object contains all the flags ([in a bit vector](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1473/proc-4.html#scrolltoc)) and process status (my suspicion is that "pause" might be a process status).

---

If the answers to those questions are "[Proc::processTable::Process](http://search.cpan.org/~durist/Proc-ProcessTable-0.45/Process/Process.pm) contains enough info for my needs", then a better solution is to use that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use warnings;
use strict;

use Proc::ProcessTable;

my $t = new Proc::ProcessTable;
foreach $p ( @{$t->table} ) {
   my $flags = $p->pid; # This is an integer containing bit vector.
   # Somehow process $flags or $p->status to find "if the process is paused"
   print "$flags\n";
   last if paused($p); # No clue how to do that without more info from you
   # May be : last if $p->status =~ /paused/;
}
```

---

However, if the native Perl process does not have enough info for you (unlikely but possible), OR if you acually desire to print exact `pflags` output as-is for some reason, the best optimization is to construct a list of PIDs for pflags natively - not as big of a win but you still lose a bunch of extra forked off processes. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use warnings;
use strict;

use Proc::ProcessTable;

my $t = new Proc::ProcessTable;
my $pids = join " ", map { $_->pid } @{$t->table};
if (open(WCF, "pflags 2>&1 $pids|")) {
    while (<WCF>) {
       next if ($_ =~ /cannot/);
       print $_;
       last if ($_ =~ /pause/);
    }
    close(WCF);
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you'd consider a "better way" in this case, but I can offer some technique guidance for the approach you already have:

- `grep '/[t]ransfile'`

  A `grep` against `ps` output often runs the risk of matching the `grep` process itself, which is almost never desired.  An easy protection against this is simply to introduce a character class of one member in the `grep` pattern argument.
- `awk '/\/[t]ransfile/{ print $2 }'`

  `grep` + `cut`, that is, field extraction following a pattern match, is an easy task for a single `awk` command.
- Don't refer to `$_`

  Tighter, more idiomatic perl would omit explicit use of `$_`.  Try `next if /cannot/` and the like.
- `open(my $wcf, ...)`

  Please use lexical filehandles, otherwise you'll be chided by those old enough to remember when we couldn't use them.  :)